# Locking the contents of shell file

Tags: shell, scripting

I have scripted a program in shell and the file is executable. Now I want to put this file on a server so that all my friends can use it but at the same time I want to make it sure that they are not allowed to fiddle with the original script.

extension of file is .bash

How I can lock the script and keep it executable at the same time?

Any suggestions...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
chmod 755 file.bash
```

Comment: well I tried it, file still opens using nano command and one can make ammendments and save it again

Comment: Well, of course _you_ can edit it. That doesn't mean they can, unless they're logged in as you.

Comment: If you don't want to be able to edit it either,  you should use `chmod 555 file.bash`

Comment: +1, but note that this is not sufficient.  Anyone with write permission on the directory can replace the file with something else.  If you are worried about a malicious "friend", security is challenging.  If you just want a friendly reminder not to edit the file, simply chmod 755 is probably adequate.